# react function component Form Component onSubmit Handler Not Working

Tags: reactjs

This is my react function component

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Form, Button } from "antd";

export default function App() {
  const hello = () => {
    console.log("enter");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form onSubmit={hello}>
        <Form.Item>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
            Apply
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am trying to invoke the function when user press the apply button, but it nothing is showing.
Where am I doing it wrong??

This is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-star-e8b2i?file=/src/App.js:0-379)

Comment: I think there is no submit prop in antd form, you can use onFinish prop

Comment: Before posting any question, please go through documentation.

Comment: https://ant.design/components/form/#Form - see `onFinish`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `onSubmit` according to `antd` document it should be `onFinish`

Here is the code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Form, Button } from "antd";
export default function App() {
  const hello = () => {
    console.log("enter");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form onFinish={hello}>
        <Form.Item>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
            Apply
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the antd documentation, Forms onFinish is the identifier for submitting callback rather than onSubmit. So you can use:

`<Form onFinish={hello}>`